# Understanding of the limit of $f\left( x\right) =\sqrt {x-1}$ as $x\rightarrow 1$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

What is the limit of $f\left( x\right) =\sqrt {x-1}$ as $x\rightarrow 1$

Wade's intro.to analysis book says that ''A reasonable answer is that the limit is zero. This function, however, does not satisfy Definition3.1 because it is not an OPEN interval containing $a=1$. Indeed, $f$ is only defined for $x\geq 1$.''

**Definition3.1**. Let $a\in\mathbb{R}$, let $I$ be an open interval which contains $a$, and let $f$ be a real function defined everywhere on $I$ except possibly at $a$. Then $f(x)$ is said to be converge to $L$, as $x$ approaches $a$, if and only if for every $\varepsilon >0$ there is a $\delta > 0$ such that

$0 < \left| x-a\right| < \delta$ implies $\left| f\left( x\right) -L\right| < \varepsilon$.

**My question is**: I couldn't understand the sentence ''it is not an OPEN interval containing $a=1$.''. Why ''it is not an OPEN interval containing $a=1$''? Also, he says that  $f$ is only defined for $x\geq 1$''? Why? Why not $x\leq 1$? Can you explain clearly?

Comment: How would you  define $\sqrt{x}$ for $x < 0$ without straying into the complex numbers?

Comment: In general, the set over which the limit is taken does not need to be an open interval, it just needs to have $a$ as a limit point. One often takes limits of the form $\lim_{x \downarrow a} f(x)$ which is the same as $\lim_{x \to a, x \ge 0 } f(x)$.

Comment: $[0,1)$ is open in $[0,\infty)$ w.r.t. the induced topology by the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$ but *not* open in $\mathbb{R}$ itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does an open interval around $a=1$ look like? It is symmetric, and this is the problem.

I.e. it looks like
$$
(1-\delta,1+\delta)
$$
for some real $\delta>0$. But as the textbook notes, if $1-\delta<x<1$ then $f(x)$ is not defined.

Comment: $x=1$? It should be $a=1$, shouldn't it? So, if $a=1$ then why $f(x)$ is not defined? Can you give a example?

Comment: Sure $a=1$ if you would like. Is $\sqrt{-1}$ defined in the real numbers?

Comment: for $a=0$, how did you obtain $\sqrt {-1}$?

Comment: where are you getting $a=0$ from? Just naively plug in $1-\delta$ into your function. Does $f(1-\delta)$ mean something in the real numbers?

Comment: we are examining the limit around the point 1 right?

Comment: hah! yes. Thanks.

Comment: Therefore, $f$ is only defined for $x \geq 1$.

Comment: Yes. No problem!

Comment: i.e., $f$ is only defined for $f\left( 1+\delta \right)$.

Comment: Yes with delta allowed to be anything non negative. The one sided limit on the right exists in other words

Answer (score 0):

In the real numbers, only the square roots of positive numbers are defined.

$\sqrt {x-1}$ is undefined when $x< 1$

We can't find two sided limit as x approaches 1.